# CDH autodeployment via API does not set the CDH version for the hosts

Tags: python, api, hadoop, cloudera

I am trying to deploy automatically the version 4.7.1 of Cloudera CDH using the Python API of the Cloudera Manager 5.3.1. I am following the example here:

https://github.com/cloudera/cm_api/blob/master/python/examples/auto-deploy/deploycloudera.py

Once that I init the cluster, create all the services that I need (Zookeeper, HDFS, MapReduce, and HBase) and start the cluster, all is ok except from a detail: All the services appear on Concerning Status because of the following issue:

Mismatched CDH versions: host has NONE but role expects 4

I've tried to update the CDH version of the cluster manually with:

```
cluster.update_cdh_version("4.7.1")
```

but that didn't update the CDH version of the hosts. Does anyone know to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted my question into the Cloudera Community forum and the offer insight that helped me find a solution. I hope it helps others:

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Autodeployment-with-CM-Manager-5-3-1-issue/m-p/24422/highlight/false